# JS, Async (lib), Express. response( ) inside async not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async.js

I tried to call res() after some async stuff finishes, inside Async.waterfall([], cb)
But as it seems, the req/res objects are not available in that scope. I call them from my callback cb.

```
function (req, res, next) {
var query = req.query;
async.waterfall([
    async.apply(userManager.register, query.username, query.email, query.password)
], function (err, result) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    if (err && err.internal == false)
        return res(err); //TypeError: res is not a function

    console.log(result);
});
```

The only solution I have in mind is, passing the req/res to my backend, and call it there.
But that would mean that my background code needs to have a req and res object. Moreover it returns something to my server, which is also bad.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's entirely correct; Express' `res` is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not about scope. It's that `res` is not a function so you can't call it like `res(err)`.  `res` is an object with methods.  You can send an error response either like this which will go to the default error handler in Express:

```
next(err)
```

Or like this:

```
res.status(500).send("Internal Error occurred").
```

which sends a 500 status on the response and then sends whatever content you want to describe the error.

I can't think of any circumstance where you want to pass the `res` object into your backend.  Your backend should fetch and return data and then your route handler should turn that data or error into a response.

Comment: Wow. I did such things for one year during my education as a software engineer. Also in that project, there are several res.send( ). I maybe had some sort of brain lag there.
Anyways, thanks for your very noob friendly answer. It worked.

Comment: @BlackPhoenix134 - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.